# Customizing css of Antd date picker

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am using antd library for date picker purposes.So far I was able to css the style the range part. but I am having some issues, can someone help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am getting this blue background between start , range and the end. I want that to be continous. (Image 1)

Also there is gap between selected rows, I want it to be purple itself. But here I see white between rows. (Image 1)

Is it possible to customize the range css, the dotted blue color when we do the range selection. Probably make that thing purple itself. (Image 2)

Also when I hover the range after the picker is closed and then opened, it should be purple. ( Image 3)

Help will be really really appreciated.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-breeze-6gmz85?file=/src/styles.css

CSS

```
p.ant-picker-panels > *:first-child button.ant-picker-header-next-btn {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.ant-picker-panels > *:first-child button.ant-picker-header-super-next-btn {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.ant-picker-panel-container,
.ant-picker-footer {
  width: 280px !important;
}

.ant-picker-footer-extra > div {
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

.ant-picker-active-bar {
  display: none;
}

.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-start .ant-picker-cell-inner {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 32px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 32px !important;
}

.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-end .ant-picker-cell-inner {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 32px !important ;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 32px !important;
}

.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-in-range::before {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger customisations you are possibly better served by creating a custom theme for the components - https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

e.g.

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.variable.min.css';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';

ConfigProvider.config({
  theme: {
    primaryColor: 'green',
  },
});
```

If you take a look at https://ant.design/components/config-provider/

It gives all the possible options for the ConfigProvider

Comment: Understood. But instead of making the global modifications, can the above be solved just using css ?